# Friendly URLs cannot load ABS_PATH in OSClass

Tags: php, osclass

I have a friendly URL module redirecting my index page to a search page. If I write index.php with my link then it redirects me to index page. If I try to access registration page it gives me error

> ABS_PATH is not loaded. Direct access is not allowed.

If I try to access any category it gives me an error such as

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /for-sale_1/toys-games-hobbies_1/ was not found on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

I have checked my error log it is giving me this error

> `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` is without `</Ifmodule>`

Works great on the local server, but not on the remove live using Apache.

Category links work on the live site but when I click to register or login or publish link it gives the error:

> ABS_PATH is not loaded. Direct access is not allowed.

Here is the rule for register that is defined in generate_rules.php

```
$rewrite->addRule('^user/register$', 'index.php?page=register&action=register');
define('REL_WEB_URL', '/home/xxx/public_html'); 
define('WEB_PATH', 'xxx.com/';);
```

Comment: What web server are you using ? Can you include the relevent .conf file for it

Comment: config.php these two lines create problem.In local server it works great  when i uploaded in live server then it create problem. I am using Apache. Categories links works in live site but when i click to register or login or publish link it gives error "ABS_PATH is not loaded. Direct access is not allowed."  .Here is the rule for register that define in generate_rules.php "$rewrite->addRule('^user/register$', 'index.php?page=register&action=register');"                                            define('REL_WEB_URL', '/home/xxx/public_html');

define('WEB_PATH', 'http://www.xxx.com/');  thanks

Answer (score 3):

You should disable MultiViews option. Write the following line in your .htaccess file (it should be in the root folder of your OSClass installation):

```
Options -MultiViews
```

Moreover, you should make sure that the .htaccess file exists.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling negotiation module of [apache](/questions/tagged/apache) or disabled MultiViews directive in server's configuration and/or `.htaccess` file

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>
```

create `.htaccess` file , copy root folder working!